# How to sum the column value dynamically?

Tags: sql, rdlc

I would like to add the column value dynamically and store the result in another column as like below.

```
Column 1    Column 2    Total
60            10         10
75             0         10
80            20         30
100           50         80
```

And also is there any possibility to done the same in RDLC.

Comment: Can you post what result you exactly expect from the above set of data. If, total is your result how r u getting this

Comment: i would like to get the output as like in the result column this is an example 
 this is me statically create for the explanation

Comment: I get it but how did you get 10 in 1st row of Column `Total`

Comment: !st row of the Column 2 is comes under the result of first row. simultaneously add the column 2 and then store it in the result column.

Comment: Do you have some column that species the order. or is that what column1 is for?

Answer (score 3):

I have given a sample query for reference let me know if you need to change something below.

check in this sample :
 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11cf3/2

```
     create table demo (
  column1 int,
  column2 int
  );

  insert into demo (Column1  ,  Column2) values
  (60 ,10),
  (75 ,0 ),
  (80 ,20),
  (80, 20) ,
  (100,50),
  (150,150),
  (160,160);

    select column1,column2 ,
    sum(column2) over (order by column1,column2 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as total
    from demo
```

Try to run same query in SSRS also.

Comment: This solution might not work if you have a duplicate column1, column2 value. 
you can add a primary key and include in `over` clause to fix it.

Comment: You could Insert another  `(80, 20  )` value into the table and try.

Comment: Thanks for checking that issue and now i have updated the query , i hope this would solve the issue you mentioned.

Comment: I have checked. its not worked when we have duplicate value. Check in this 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d87fb/1 link.